# How to display local language database data in spring jsp

Tags: java, .net, spring, jsp, localization

[image]

Here is screen developed in .NET.  I want to do same in Java. How?

On click of English menu it has to translate from local lang to English in Spring mvc or Java.

I tried doing using I10N but i found it no use.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some code that you have tried?

I worked on a project a couple years ago that displayed multiple languages through a translation bundle. I used a `Request.dto` to get a user's session info (country code, language code, etc.). I then used a `User.dto` that extended `Request.dto` with a getter like this:

`/**
     * @return The end user's language code associated with their session
     */
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }`

This was used to access a translation bundle associated with the User's country code, language code, etc.

This is just one example of a way to do this. Try a few poc's, and see what best fits your use case.